# In Unity, how can I modify the shape of a sprite?

Tags: c#, 2d, unity

I am new to Unity and programming in general, however, I wanted to know how to change a sprite's shape. I want to do this while the game is running, so I was thinking about removing a set of pixels given some condition after an event has happened and then adjusting the collider around the object. However, I don't know how to do this. I have searched in YouTube and Google but so far I have not found anything that is useful to me. 

My first thoughts were to make the pixels in a sprite's texture transparent given a condition, and I was able to achieve this, but when the time came to translate the texture into the shape of the sprite I failed miserably. Then I thought about using meshes, but I think that meshes might be too hard on the engine and cause some slowdown. I want to make a digging game where I can dig through many different objects and those are my ideas thus far. If you think there are better ways or know of a place where I can learn or, ideally, were willing to give me some coding techniques in C# for achieving the above, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you considered using block based digging, in other words when you dig it removes some blocks from the scene (like Terraria or Starbound).

Comment: Yes :D, but i'd like it to be smoother, I don't like those blocky aspects, I'd like to make the terrain continuous. :)

Comment: Do you only ever dig open pits, or can the player tunnel horizontally?

Comment: @DMGregory, he can tunnel horizontally, but I think that maybe if there is a script for digging open pits, maybe we could rotate the terrain ninety degrees and do it horizontally (?) I am not sure :P.

Comment: Could you do something clever with masks? I.e. every time you dig make the mask a bit larger and the mask covers the sprite and reveals the background?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to ask about *modifying the shape of a sprite* not "destructible obstacles/terrain in 2D game"? I think the title is misleading - you dont care how you achieve it, right?

Comment: @wondra I don't care how to achieve it, I used that title because I thought the terrain had to be a sprite.

Comment: @Malrig, I am willing to use any method as long as the terrain gets modified (both its appearance and its colliders) :).

Comment: Ah ok, the mask won't affect the collider only the visuals. I just thought of it because I am looking into mask to define vision cones etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I thought about using meshes, but I think that meshes might be too hard on the engine and cause some slowdown.

Let me check my clock...yes, it is 2016, having 1 mesh shouldn't slow down anything.

What you need here is a tile based terrain (e.g. terraria) with marching squares. Marching squares is an algorithm, wich is made to smooth out 2d tile based terrain.

Comment: I researched Marching Squares, a really nice solution, but how do I make the mesh take on the form of an initial terrain image? Would I not need to subdivide the mesh into many different squares?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Yeah, you do need to have squares. I have found somewhere a nice tutorial about this, I try to find it.

Comment: Found it https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial

Comment: Alright, I implemented the code in the first and second videos but instead of randomly generating the cave, I used an image as a blueprint for the map(copying pixel by pixel into the integer map), it kind of slows down the game by a tiny bit, it is only a 100×100 image, is there a way around this?

Comment: @GuachoPerez Make sure to have as few I/O as possible. I'm not a unity progranner btw, I only like to go around and give tips for people about different algorithms.

Comment: Done, is it possible to implement a linear interpolation to make the terrain look smoother? Even with marching squares it seems rather jagged. What type of collider would I use then?

Comment: @Guacho Perez There are ways, but they realy on creating the mesh from a freeform shape, and comverting it to voxels. Again, I don't use unity, I use algorithms